# How do I replace a plugin present in Plug-in Dependencies in RCP project with latest version?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created a RCP Application. Currently it is using **org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.107.0.v20180611-0422.jar**. I have a lastest version of SWT jar(V3.11) which I want to add it to plug-in dependencies.
How do I do it?

PS : I'm using Photon version of eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to the plug-in. The choice of dependency plug-in versions is done automatically using the plug-ins in the "Target Platform" that you are using. The versions shown are the plug-ins in your current target platform. You change to a different set of plug-in versions by defining a target platform in  the Preferences in 'Plug-in Development > Target Platform' and making that target active.

The 'Require-Bundle' entry in the plug-in's MANIFEST.MF can specify a range of versions which are allowed for the dependency.

So

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.di;bundle-version="0.10.1"
```

says that **at least** version '0.10.1' of the 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.di' is required.